# Validating Peer in Blockchain Service in Bluemix does not recognize shim.ChaincodeStubInterface?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger

I am able to deploy a chaincode in a locally running Hyperledger validating peer.

The chaincode uses the following object:

```
shim.ChaincodeStubInterface
```

I tried to deploy the same chaincode in the validating peer of a Bluemix Blockchain service.  However, the deployment is not successful as it does not recognize `shim.ChaincodeStubInterface`.

I checked sample chaincodes in Bluemix and found out that it uses the `shim.ChaincodeStub` instead of `shim.ChaincodeStubInterface`.

Does this mean that the Hyperledger API in Bluemix does not recognize shim.ChaincodeStubInterface?  If yes, when will the API of the Bluemix Blockchain service be updated to the latest version?

Comment: please show your complete error ?

Answer (score 0):

The bluemix service was using an older version **v0.5**  of the Hyperledger Fabric before November 10 2016. This version used the old syntax i.e `shim.ChaincodeStub`

The [bluemix service status page](https://bluemix-service-status.blockchain.ibm.com/) shows that on 10-11-2016 the Fabric version on bluemix has been updated to **v0.6.1**. This newer version should be using the new syntax that you are trying to use i.e `shim.ChaincodeStubInterface`. So if you simply order the bluemix service again, it should fix your issue.